# VS Code : Syntax Highlight for Mustache code inside <script> tags in HTML file

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting, mustache

On our company we use [Mustache](https://mustache.github.io/) templates inside embedded `<script type="mustache">` tags on `.html` files. Example:

```html
<div>
  Some rendered content Here.
  <div id="target"></div>
</div>

<script type="mustache" id="people_template">
  Here some people names.
  {{#people}}
    Name: {{name}}
  {{/people}}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  // some code to render the template to the DOM
</script>
```

VS Code correctly highlights JS code in embedded `<script>` or `<script type="text/javascript">` tags.

The `type` attribute is important:

- It does not highlight it if `<script type="blah">`
- It does highlight it as HTML if `<script type="text/html">`

How can I instruct VS Code to Highlight embedded `<script type="mustache">` as Mustache, using extensions like [vscode-mustache-syntax-highlighting](https://github.com/dnwhte/vscode-mustache-syntax-highlighting)?